# MPH program only allowing "hours" to be inputted and not "minutes"

Tags: java

I am making a program to calculate Miles Per Hour, and I am having trouble with inputting the minutes. As long as I put hours into the program it works fine, but not minutes. I have two classes:

CLASS ONE:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import static java.lang.System.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class MilesPerHour
{
    private int hours, minutes, distance;
    private double mph;
    private float time;

    public MilesPerHour()
    {
        setNums(0,0,0);
        mph=0.0;
    }

    public MilesPerHour(int dist, int hrs, int mins)
    {
    }

    public void setNums(int dist, int hrs, int mins)
    {
        distance = dist;
        hours = hrs;
        minutes = mins;
        time = ((hours*60)+minutes/60);
    }

    public void calcMPH()
    {
        mph = distance/time;
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("at "+mph+" MPH, you can go "+distance+" miles in "+hours+" hours and "+minutes+" minutes.");
    }
}
```

CLASS TWO (test class):

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import static java.lang.System.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class MPHRunner
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(in);

        out.print("Enter the distance :: ");
        int dist = keyboard.nextInt();

        out.print("Enter the hours :: ");
        int hrs = keyboard.nextInt();

        out.print("Enter the minutes :: ");
        int mins = keyboard.nextInt();

        MilesPerHour test = new MilesPerHour(dist, hrs, mins);
        test.setNums(dist, hrs, mins);
        test.calcMPH();
        test.print();

        //add more test cases


    }
}
```

Thank you for all help, and keep in mind I am a beginner so I could have overlooked a very small problem in the code.

Comment: Any chance you swapped hours and minutes in the time calculation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time = (hours*60) + minutes/60` doesn't make sense units-wise (it implies that an hour is 3600 minutes). But what's more, because `minutes` is an `int`, `minutes/60` is integer division, meaning that the result will always be 0 if `minutes` is less than 60.

Since you have `mph = distance / time` it makes sense that `time` is in units of hours. So you don't have to multiply `hours` by 60 at all. And you can solve the problem with integer division by casting to `float`. All in all, you should end up with

```
time = hours + (float)minutes / 60
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! I figured it could have been my math as it is hard for me to translate equations into Java.